# How to mount a folder in a container as locally

Tags: docker, containers, backup

by defauld when mounting a volumen in a container, the container see the host folder mounted by shfs. I have an app that only see local folder so it discard the folder for being considered remote.

Is there any way to mount a volume in a container like locally?
My docker:

```
/usr/local/emhttp/plugins/dynamix.docker.manager/scripts/docker run -d --name="iaso_backup_manager" --net="bridge" --privileged="true" -e TZ="Europe/Paris" -e HOST_OS="unRAID" -e "DEVICE"="device" -e "PASSWORD"="password" -p 5000:5000/tcp -p 5314:5314/tcp -v "/mnt/user/":"/mnt/":ro nitelmursoftware/iaso_backup_manager
```

my docker has the folder like this:

```
root@eb878b3879cb:/# mount | grep mnt
shfs on /mnt type fuse.shfs (ro,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

that mount type/way is not valid for the app I created the container, IASO Backup Manager :-(

Comment: How much data is inside the mount point? As an alternative you can copy it from the volume to the container's filesystem.